# SciPy ODE Solver Ignoring function

Tags: python

I am trying to make Scipy's ODE solver solve the Lorentz Force differential equations. It does not solve the equations correctly with the B-field component because it completely ignores the E-field no matter how large I make it (Which is also why I know it is ignoring it). Why is this? I have already tried modifying the sign on the E-field function too.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#import random
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d as p3


#Mirroring Angle to Recreate
ThetaMirror = 40
TStep = 1
TFinal = 10
P0 = [0.,0.02,0.]
V0 = [1,0,0]
t = np.linspace(0,TFinal,num=(TFinal/TStep))

#Physical/Natural Constants
q_e = -1
m_e = 1
QeMe = q_e/m_e
u0 = 1

#Math
ICs = np.concatenate((P0,V0),axis=0)

def BField(x,y,z):

    Bx = 0
    By = 0
    Bz = 1

    BVec = np.array([Bx,By,Bz])

    return BVec


def EField(x,y,z):

    Ex = 0
    Ey = 0
    Ez = 2.8E8*z**4
    EVec = np.array([Ex,Ey,Ez])

    return EVec


def LorentzForce(PosVel,t,Constants):

    x,y,z,vx,vy,vz = PosVel
    Ex,Ey,Ez,Bx,By,Bz,QeMe = Constants

    EFInput = np.array([Ex,Ey,Ez])
    BFInput = np.array([Bx,By,Bz])
    VelInput = np.array([vx,vy,vz])

    Accel = QeMe * (EFInput + np.cross(VelInput, BFInput))   

    LFEqs = np.concatenate((VelInput, Accel), axis = 0)

    return LFEqs


Ex,Ey,Ez = EField(P0[0],P0[1],P0[2])
Bx,By,Bz = BField(P0[0],P0[1],P0[2])
#Ex = Ey = Ez = 0
AllConstantInputs = [Ex,Ey,Ez,Bx,By,Bz,QeMe]
ParticleTrajectory = odeint(LorentzForce, ICs, t, args=(AllConstantInputs,))

print(ParticleTrajectory)
print(Bz)

fig = plt.figure()
particleplot = fig.add_subplot(111,projection='3d')
particleplot.plot(ParticleTrajectory[:, 0],ParticleTrajectory[:, 1],ParticleTrajectory[:, 2],'b')
particleplot.set_xlabel('x axis')
particleplot.set_ylabel('y axis')
particleplot.set_zlabel('z axis')
particleplot.legend(loc='best')
particleplot.grid()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define `P0[2] = 0.`. The electric field function computes `Ez = 2.8E8*z**4`. Hence, python is not ignoring the E-field function, you are putting its z component to zero yourself: `z = P0[2] = 0`.

Comment: Yeah I also realized this a few days ago. Silly mistake!